# ASSERT: condition (intersectAt.size() % 2) == 0 false in function calculateAttenuation

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I had this error at 258s in my simulation, I have consulted the response in this link "[Model error: ASSERT: condition (intersectAt.size() % 2) == 0 false in function calculateAttenuation, veins/modules/obstacle/Obstacle.cc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896494/model-error-assert-condition-intersectat-size-2-0-false-in-function-c)" and I removed the ASSERT statement.

I have done the simulation again but at 258s there is no error but the simulation was blocked and nothing was happening.

How can I correct this problem please?

Comment: which version of Veins do you use?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I use Veins-4a2.

Comment: As you might have noticed @ChristophSommer (the main developer of Veins) in his answer to your linked question, clearly states that this is a known issue for Veins versions up to 4.4. While you are using 4a2 which is almost two years old. Before getting into the details of solving your problem, I would highly recommend you to upgrade to the latest Veins (version 4.5), that might solve a lot of other issues along the path too. And yes, it is worth the time and the hassle. If the problem persists after the update, then your obstacle definitions might be faulty.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I installed veins-4.5 and I exectuted my simulation but after 13s it shows me this error that I have not with veins-4a2: Undeclared signal emitted (@signal missing from NED file?) How can I resolve it please? I need that my simulation runs until 258s to see if there is a problem or not.

Comment: that seems like a different problem, hence it is better to post it in a different question in SO, so it serves for future reference for the others as well. Provide the link when you post the Q so I can see it

Comment: I solved the problem of signals and I am trying to simulate with the new version veins-4.5.