# Switching off ObstacleShadowing in veins

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I was working on veins 4.4 then moved to the latest version. I was facing the issue of [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896494/model-error-assert-condition-intersectat-size-2-0-false-in-function-c) so commented out that code. Now I do not want Obstacle shadowing how I can do that? 
Removing

```
<AnalogueModel type="SimpleObstacleShadowing">
    <parameter name="carrierFrequency" type="double" value="5.890e+9"/>
    <obstacles>
        <type id="building" db-per-cut="9" db-per-meter="0.4" />
    </obstacles>
</AnalogueModel>
```

from config.xml and obstacle definition from `.ini` file enough? Will there be any side effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely correct: after removing this part of the channel configuration, obstacle shadowing will no longer be taken into account.

Note you might even want to alter the channel configuration further, to better capture the type of channel in your scenario.